# Why does this basic class not work?

Tags: php, class

I could not understand why my class does not work. It doesn't return anything. Is there any mistake?

```
class User  {

public $first_name;
public $last_name;

public function full_name() {
if(isset($this->first_name) && isset($this->last_name)) {
    return $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;
 } else {
    return "No name!";
 }
}

public  function assign () {

$this->first_name = "Name";
$this->last_name =  "Surname";
 }

}


$user = new User();
$user->assign();
$user->full_name();



?>
```

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: @kalaba2003: why should it display anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you forget to "echo" the returned value?

```
echo $user->full_name();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning, not printing.

Try printing the returned values:

```
echo $user->full_name();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `empty()` function instead of `isset()`.